# set intervals for plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Apologies if this has already been asked.

I need plot a huge array which I am plotting the size of the array is 36698, I have set the axis values so that the graph starts at 0 but extends a little further so that I am able view all of the readings properly, but the graph is actually a step wise function, Is there any way I can define intervals, so that the entire graph looks more spread out, rather than constrained in the beginning. [image: Here] in graph the values start from 0 but most of the values are in the range of 0 to 1.5 which I want plot so that the plot values look uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logarithmic scale. `set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')`